# Prevent values of a certain type in an object

Tags: typescript

I have a type `SecretString` which can contain any kind of sensitive information that I may handle on my server but which I don't want to accidentally log out. It's a branded string type:

```
type SecretString = string & {__brand: "secret"}
```

My logging function takes a string and an object (`any`, currently) which can contain whatever additional information might be necessary. Is there a way for me to express that second parameter as a type that can be an arbitrary object but will complain if a `SecretString` is present? Nested checking would be great but I would be happy with first level.

As the `SecretString` works just like a string, it typically comes from a function like this one:

```
function decryptString(encryptedString: EncryptedString): SecretString {
  // ...
}
```

So this is an example of a scenario where I would like an error message:

```
const keys = decryptString(encryptedKeys);

logger.info('This should not compile!', { 
  valueThatIsOk: 'this is ok', 
  valueThatShouldFail: keys 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursively is beyond my TypeScript at present, but at the top level a mapped type should work:

```typescript
type SecretString = string & {__brand: "secret"};

function log<ObjType>(msg: any, obj: ObjType extends SecretString ? never : ObjType) {
    console.log(msg, obj);
}

let x: SecretString = "example" as SecretString;

log("hi", {example: 42});
log("hi", "more info");
log("hi", x);
//        ^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− error as desired
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyhDGAnCwbEQSwHYHMoF4oBndbPAMigG8B9GgI0QEMsATALigCIiFlguAXwDcAKFEAzAK5Z4wDAHssUADYKcAHgDy9AFYAVcBAB8ACgC2RHJxYgANFAV7OOg0agQAHsAhsisPhQ0TFwoAH4oLAgANwhEKBc9Q0gASmpRKEyoeCUiBRUIADo1HAsrByddFLFBcQLgKE9OOCQg0lDCLi8mczACrigmfxb+YLIxURLTLgALDC4HKm7egs4AFgAmQWrJ9Wm5he5zBWQobAkFLh2p2fmHTx2Aekes16gAPUAkIm+f37+PRCIE6DfysCBEDDIViiIA)

For passing an object instead, it's still the same thing but in an object structure:

```typescript
function log<ObjType extends object>(
    msg: any,
    obj: {[key in keyof ObjType]: ObjType[key] extends SecretString ? never : ObjType[key]}
) {
    console.log(msg, obj);
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyhDGAnCwbEQSwHYHMoF4oBndbPAMigG8B9GgI0QEMsATALigCIiFlguAXwDcAKFEAzAK5Z4wDAHssUADYKcAHgDy9AFYAVcNAgAPYBDZEoCvQmAA+ABSiorqAFsiOTixAAaFzcbXU4qAG0AawgQKGwoKJAFCSgdAyMAXU5Uw0hI6PSoU3NLWD4UNExcKAB+KCwIADcIRCgsvRyIPJB0wVEASmpA13glIgUVCAA6NRxHTxw-az0+sV7RCeB46KJOOCRy0irCLlMmdzAJrigmKz3+CrIxdfVHAHJ9AAsMKyIPhSkVKw6gpNiNzhgJgBCV6LKhQQINJgqKQQT5MYAASSIWginFewC+Vm+1giMPhrkRyNRH3RMD+ANYADEmBDOAkrKJBCtREA)

(If you want both, you can combine them in a union.)

Comment: I appreciate this but it's just one level too "top" :-) Even though strings and other primitive values are allowed as the second parameter, I always pass an object. So when I said that nested is not necessary, I meant beyond that level.

Comment: @KristianDupont - I've added an example that handles an object and your sample call.